# CollectionView Custom Layout 2 cells same row

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, xcode7

i want to achieve a custom `CollectionView` where the part after header has two `cells` on the same row and the rest of the cells get the full width of the container like this.

[image]

The problem is that i need these to work for different screen sizes and even the screen size i test with (iPhone 6) doesn't work as expected.

The output is something like this.
[image]

I have `custom` class cells for each section, i have the `CustomFlowLayout` class only i don't exactly know how to do this!

Comment: put project on Github and share link will  help u out to implement this else you should use autolayout . Just consider Collectionview as Tableview , it helps you manage things easily.

Comment: I managed to do it finally with sizeOfItemAtIndexPath , giving the cells the width of (view.bounds.width/2) if you know a better way to do it , i will happily post the project on github.

Comment: yea sure , update it